# Perfect forwarding const ref deduction error

Tags: c++, c++17, perfect-forwarding

I've written a super simple thread wrapper that takes a function and runs it in a thread and provides a simple mechanism to signal the thread when it's time to quit. The start function looks like

```
//tw.hpp

class ThreadWrapper
{
public:
  // ...snipped ...
  template<typename... Args>
  bool start(Args&& ... args)
  {
    ft_ = std::async(std::launch::async, std::forward<Args>(args)...  );
    return true;
  }
};
```

When I use it for a non-member function, I need to pass in a const ref of the wrapper into the function that is running to provide a handle the function can use to know when to quit:

```
void lone_worker(const ThreadWrapper& tw)
{
  while (!tw.is_quit_requested())
  {
    std::cout << "working hard alone\n";
    sleep(1);
  }
}

void nonmember_demo()
{
  ThreadWrapper tw;
  tw.start(&lone_worker, std::cref(tw)); // the cref is need to avoid hundreds of lines of compiler template puke with no useful error messages
  sleep(5);
  std::cout << "quitting\n";
  tw.request_quit();
}
```

I was caught off guard when I originally compiled it without using `std::cref` by literally hundreds of lines of compiler template puke (gcc 8.1.0) and no clear reason.  Is there something I haven't done right with the perfect forwarding to require the use of cref?  I assume it's partially caused by the class being non-copyable (it contains a std::future), which smells a little since at least  I assume no copy should be made in the first place.
Full exampl here: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0eb4d6160b44764a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which smells a little since at least I assume no copy should be made in the first place

You assume incorrectly. [`async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) mostly just forwards to [`thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread), which starts by executing:

> ```
> std::invoke(decay_copy(std::forward<Function>(f)), 
>             decay_copy(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
> ```

This does copy all the arguments. The point of the reference wrapper is to avoid this copy - instead of copying the `ThreadWrapper` object (which is noncopyable), you're copying a `std::reference_wrapper<ThreadWrapper const>` (which is copyable).

From the linked cppreference page for `thread`:

> The arguments to the thread function are moved or copied by value. If a reference argument needs to be passed to the thread function, it has to be wrapped (e.g. with `std::ref` or `std::cref`).

Comment: So it's not a perfect forwarding issue, it's the way std::thread is implemented (which I guess makes sense to avoid potential race conditions)

Comment: @schrödinbug s/implemented/designed